# Why is PHP still showing my method as Undefined?

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to save user into db, everything seems to be fine, except one problem

Why everytime I try to call save_user(...) I'm getting

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function check_user() in ... on line 47
```

connect class:

```
    class Db_connect {

    function __construct(){

    }
    function __destruct(){

    }
    function connect(){
        $connect = MySQL_Connect ( "host", "user", "pass")  or Die("Couldn't connect to DB");
        MySQL_Select_Db("db") or Die("Couldn't find database db");
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");

        return $conect;
    }
    function close(){
        MySQL_close();
    }

}
```

Functions class

```
class Db_functions {
    private $db;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Db_connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }
    function __destruct(){

    }

    public function check_user($email,$pass){
        $result = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'";
        $sql = mysql_query($result);

        if ( mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function save_user($id,$name,$pass,$email,$country){
        $result = "INSERT INTO user(id,name,pass,email,country) VALUES('$id','$name','$pass','$email','$country')";

        if ( check_user($email,$pass) ) { //here's line 47
            return false;
        }
        if ( mysql_query($result) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm getting really tired :D I can't find nothing wrong

Comment: You've got a typo in your connect function `return $conect;` should be `return $connect;`

Comment: thank's. that would be another problem later :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the class member as

```
if ( check_user($email,$pass) ) {
```

which is not correct , you need to do as

```
if ( $this->check_user($email,$pass) ) {
```

This needs to be corrected across your code.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Oh god! Thanks very much :) I'm mixing java,php and batch at one time and this type of mistake is very bad